# How to scale image height with vh div

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I'm trying to get this image to scale to the browser by height so it never causes scrolling ( it will be a light box with different image ratios) However it doesn't want to resize the image to fill the parent div and I'm not sure why. It also scales by sliding to the left rather than centering.
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/hrfLwyjd/

```
<style> 
.modal-content {
    width:80vw;
    height:80vh;
    background:yellow;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}   
.mySlides img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
</style>


 <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
     <img src="images/5_2.jpg">
    </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should fix it:

```css
.modal-content {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mySlides img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Update:
As per comment, it looks like you also want to enlarge the image when it's smaller than the lightbox. For that, the simplest solution is:

```css
.modal-content {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.mySlides {
  background: transparent no-repeat center / contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="mySlides" style="background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, this has fixed it for scaling down, however it still stays a small centered image on larger windows like on the top right just centered now.

Comment: @duckyduck, why would you want a lightbox to enlarge an image above its actual size so it looks pixelated? You seem to want to achieve `background-size:contain` behavior using an `<img>` instead of `background-image`. I suggest you just use `background-image`.

Comment: I'll look into background-image thanks so much, I guess I was trying a haphazard way of being able to put it on much larger screens without having to increase file size for mobile, but that's another issue all together. I'm learning with trial by fire.

Sorry to pester you with questions,so total optional bonus question. Do you perhaps also know of a way to size the .modal-content width to the mySlides? 
I'm using modal-content to align my prev,next,and close buttons to prevent pasting the buttons on every individual slide.

Comment: @ducky, answering questions asked in comments goes against the principles of SO, as you'd be the only one benefiting the answer, as opposed to the whole community, if you asked a new question. That being said, the proper way to do this is to have a centered element with header/footer and body areas. Put the content in the body and whatever you want into the decorators.  Sizing  elements around the contents of a central layout unit is not a problem with CSS. If you're out to learn, you'd benefit a lot by looking at lightbox plugins/libraries, inspect the CSS and see how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use width:100vmin and height:vmin like this:

```
.modal-content {
  background:yellow;
  position: relative;
}   
.mySlides img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:80vmin;
  height:80vmin;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto:
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your modal-content height same as the image height. img width can be half of the modal-content, as you want it to keep it in center. Also, using flex can give you the exact result that you want.

```
.modal-content {
    width:80vw;
    height:80vh;
    background:yellow;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}   
.mySlides img {
    width:40vw;
    height:80vh;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrfLwyjd/6/)

Comment: This distorts the image so it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cN0XcVQ.jpg">
    </div>

 </div>
```

CSS

```
.modal-content {
    width:80vw;
    height:80vh;
    background:yellow;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}   
.mySlides img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
  flex:1;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything unfortunately. :(