# Image not resizing correctly on css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an image display on my browser window so no matter how I resize it, changing height or width I can always see the image fully. Right now my css is like this:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

And the width changes correctly, but if the image is too tall a scroll appears and I can't see the image fully. Is there any way to display it correctly? Here's the html:

```
<div>
  <img src={{imagenActual}} >
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max-height` just like you used max-width, to define the value of the image's maximum height which it should not exceed.

With `vh`, you can specify units in view-height, instead of using `%`

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180148/how-to-scale-image-height-with-vh-div)

```css
.imageDiv{
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageDiv">
  <img src="https://www.industrialempathy.com/img/remote/ZiClJf-1920w.jpg" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can set your image URL in the CSS you can try the following solution.

This will automatically resize your image based on the current height of your browser window, try to play around with the "height" value".

HTML:

```
<div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2813579.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the image as a background in css. This will then allow you to use the background-size property.

```
// html
<div class="cover-image" style="background-image: url({{imagenActual}});">
  
</div>

// css
.cover-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```